# Remove Freckles from Simple Binary Image

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I have the following NumPy array of a running man, which you can download here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SfIEqGsBV_vA7iP4UjLdklLJlLdDzozL/view?usp=sharing

To display it, use this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
data = np.load('running_man.npy')
# plot data
plt.imshow(data)
```

[image]

As you can see there is a lot of noise (freckles) in the image. I would like to get rid of it and retrieve a clean image of the runner. Any idea of how to do it?

***This is what I have done so far***:

```
from skimage import measure
# Find contours at a constant value of 1
contours = measure.find_contours(data, 1, fully_connected='high')

# Select the largest contiguous contour
contour = sorted(contours, key=lambda x: len(x))[-1]

# Create an empty image to store the masked array
r_mask = np.zeros_like(data, dtype='bool')

# Create a contour image by using the contour coordinates rounded to their nearest integer value
r_mask[np.round(contour[:, 0]).astype('int'), np.round(contour[:, 1]).astype('int')] = 1

# Fill in the hole created by the contour boundary
r_mask = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(r_mask)

# Invert the mask since one wants pixels outside of the region
r_mask = ~r_mask

plt.imshow(r_mask)
```

[image]

**... but as you can see the outline is very rough !**
What works well is to upload the image to an online jpg to SVG converter -> this makes the lines super smooth. ... but I want to be able to do it in python.

Idea:
I am looking for something that can **keep the sharp corners**, maybe something that detects the gradient along the edge and only keeps the point where the gradient is above a certain threshold...

Comment: was something about this question changed?

Comment: @IanChu Yes, I changed the link to data. It should work now! (Had to delete the old question and repost, for some reason it was not working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific image you can just use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.load('running_man.npy')
data[data > 1] = 0
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.imshow(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This result is rather clean. Can you tell me why there is a slight green border around the running man? Thanks.

Comment: There are two sources of the greenish border. First, the code above does not create a binary image - there are some intermediate values of pixels left over from the original image. Second, the function `plt.imshow()`  displaying the image performs some interpolation of colors of pixels so that lines look smoother. You can turn it off by using `plt.imshow(data, interpolation="none")` but then the edges will be more jagged. In general, it is not possible to get smooth edges on a binary, raster image. For this you would need to convert the image into a vector format such as SVG.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful comment! Is it possible to do this conversion to a vector format in python? Do you know?

Comment: I have not tried it myself, but perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56396804/converting-a-bmp-png-jpeg-to-an-svg-file-using-python) will help.

Answer (score 2):

For a method that preserves the corners better, we can use median filters, but force the preservation of corners.

Masked Image

[image]

Mask after filtering

[image]

Recolored

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("run.png");
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

# make mask
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU);

# median filter
med = cv2.medianBlur(thresh, 11);
med[thresh == 255] = 255;

# inverse filter
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(med);
med = cv2.medianBlur(mask, 3);
med[mask == 255] = 255;

# recolor
color = np.zeros_like(img);
color[med == 0] = (66, 239, 245);
color[med == 255] = (92, 15, 75);

# show
cv2.imshow("colored", color);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```

Comment: That's a very good approach, but I am looking for something that can keep the sharp corners, i.e. something that detects the gradient along the edge and only keeps the point where the gradient is above a certain threshold...

Comment: Thank you very much! It's much better now! There are still some ripples though... What do you think about the gradient approach that I suggested?

Comment: I don't know how to go about implementing that idea.

Comment: Sure, no worries and thank you so much for your answer!